# SDWebImage Load image with authorization header

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to load images in my objective-c application. For some images, I need to set the authorization. I searched in the documentation but all I found is a simple load from url. Is there a way to load images using Authorization?

Comment: I haven't used it before, but it appears that `SDWebImageManager` has an `imageDownloader` property and `SDWebImageDownloader` has various properties for authorization (e.g. `urlCredential`, `username`, `password`)

Comment: @KevinBallard please how can I use the SDWebImageManager after setting the header? How can I after that load image from url?

Comment: Again, I haven't used SDWebImage, but I would assume that if you modify `[SDWebImageManager sharedManager]` then it will affect all future loads.

Comment: did you get the solution for this, i am also getting the same issue. -999 error getting.... Please let us know if you find the answer.

Comment: You can use Kingfisher pod for this.

Comment: @LilyBallard you are right, it works well. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon AWS S3 service for loading images with authorization. You can refer documentation of amazon web service because in sdwebimage we can't do image authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I think, It will resolve your problem:

1. Download Image.
2. In completion Block check your authorization status.
3. If authorized then set Image.

   ```
   SDWebImageDownloader.shared().downloadImage(with: URL(string:YOUR URL), options: [], progress: nil) { (image, data, error, status) in
       if status == true{
           if AUTHORIZED{
               IMAGEVIEW.image = image
           }
       }
   }
   ```